# UIRefreshControl pull length

Tags: objective-c, ios, uirefreshcontrol

Looked around at stackoverflow but couldn't find a answer to this question:
Is there any way to change how much a tableview has to be pulled down for the UIRefreshControl to start refreshing? Cause pulling 45% of the screen seems a little overkill.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way of changing it using the `UIRefreshControl` component provided by Apple, since it's behavior is managed privately by the implementation of `UITableViewController`.

If you really want that kind of customization you may consider the open-source component [ODRefreshControl](https://github.com/jyhnihao/ODRefreshControl) and try to tweak its parameters.

Comment: Any idea how to tweak those parameters to reduce the pull length?

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** needs change this behave, you can do like thie:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    @try {
        [self.refreshControl setValue:@(60) forKey:@"_snappingHeight"];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
    }
}
```

More detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40461168/945906