# UIRefreshControl needs to be pulled down too far

Tags: ios

I'm trying to implement a `UIRefreshControl` in my project on a `UICollectionView`. It works as intended, but I need to pull the the `UICollectionView` about 3x as much as the height of the `refreshControl` when it's spinning (once the user has let go). I've seen other apps where you only need to pull down to the height of the `refreshControl` when it's spinning. How do I change the amount I need to pull down?

Code:

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  self.refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
  [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshFavorites) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  [self.collectionView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
  self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
}
```

Attached are pictures to help visualize what I mean. My `collectionView` has one row (solid red). The space between the red and the `refreshControl` is simply the space I'm pulling down to try to activate the `refreshControl`.

In this image I've almost activated the control and I've already pulled down a considerable amount on the screen.

[image]

In this image I've activated the control and it's starting to load (after it jumps ~20-30 pix, but it still highlights how significant this is)

[image]

This image shows the control in its "resting" state after it's been activated and is doing the animation.

[image]

I've tried setting the frame of the `UIRefreshControl` to try to control the height, but this doesn't work. I've also changed around the size in `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath` which hasn't helped.

Comment: Did you end up solving this problem? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 26):

If a UIRefreshControl needs to be pulled down too far to trigger, it might be a bug of iOS SDK.

I recommend solve this situation with a view controller’s help:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // Force update the snapping height of refresh control.
    [self.refreshControl didMoveToSuperview];
}
```

Also if you don’t mind use private API and needs more accurate control, you can write like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    @try {
        [self.refreshControl setValue:@(60) forKey:@"_snappingHeight"];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
    }
}
```

This works on iOS 7-10. No App Store review issue.

---

**Look inside**

UIRefreshControl has a property called snappingHeight. This property controls the distance user needs pull down. But unfortunately, this value not set properly always, especially you have a custom view hierarchy.

UIRefreshControl have a private method calls `_updateSnappingHeight`, this method also called in `didMoveToSuperview`. So an manual `didMoveToSuperview` call can update the wrong snapping value.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks, it save my day!

Comment: Brilliant! I had an issue on iPhone 5s iOS 12.3.1. Hope this bug will be fixed soon.

Comment: On iOS 13+ I can suggest to call it in a `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Answer (score 5):

For people still looking for an answer to this. I have a definite and best possible answer so far...

SWIFT 3:

Inside viewDidLoad() :

```
self.refresher = UIRefreshControl()
self.refresher.tintColor = UIColor.red
self.scrollView.addSubview(self.refresher)
```

Next If your View is a ViewController - implement the ScrollViewDelegate like so:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
```

Once you have your scrollView @IBOulet linked...
Go ahead and set the scrollView delegate to self inside viewDidLoad() like so:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self
```

Next, since you have the delegates set up, set up the scrollViewDidScroll Function and implement it, to check if the person pulled down passed -90 like so :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == self.scrollView
    {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -90  && !self.refresher.isRefreshing{
            self.refresher.beginRefreshing()
            self.Refresh()
            print("zz refreshing")
        }
    }
}
```

**Now, notice we do not have the**

```
self.refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.Refresh()), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

and nor do we need it at all. Instead we are calling beginRefresh() followed by the actual function... Just make sure to call **endRefresh()** somewhere you want it to end.

Comment: Take note that the scroll view will still call `beginRefreshing()`  when scrolling (dragging) to the original offset.

Comment: @WaylanSands just check for `isDragging` property of the scrollView

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I found the issue with UIviewcontroller's simulated size that was free from.

I just make changes in the simulated size of UIViewcontroller that is fixed.

This one change solved my issue.

Comment: You ended my 4 hours of frustration :)

Answer (score 3):

Non of the solutions listed here worked for me. 
The solution I found is using `refresh.didMoveToSuperview()` in `viewDidAppear`.

Complete solution:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        refresh.didMoveToSuperview()
    }
```

Comment: this is literally one of the listed solutions in this thread, yours is about 3 years too late :)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift

Based on @BB9z Objective-C answer:

```
refreshControl.setValue(100, forKey: "_snappingHeight")
```

Answer (score 0):

Had an issue with this in iOS 10.2 So for anyone still suffering with this, I found a way to do it without the need to touch the private API methods (although this did fix the issue as well).

I found that I was having an issue when the device was rotating on iPad. UIRefreshControl was behaving ok in portrait but would start to go wrong when the device was rotated. After that it didn't matter what orientation it was in, it would always need to be dragged way too far than needed to be activated.

My solution was based on this answer: [Offsetting UIRefreshControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309268/offsetting-uirefreshcontrol)

I tried setting the frame of the UIRefreshControl whenever the device rotated and it worked. Its not ideal as it doesn't use AutoLayout but its a bit cleaner than playing with private APIs.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

-(void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [self.refreshControl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    [self.refreshControl setNeedsLayout];

}
```