# Swift UIRefreshControl not working on iPhone 8

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uirefreshcontrol

I have an `UIRefreshControl` which works on every device except iPhone 8 (works neither on a physical device or an emulator).

On an iPhone 8 the refresh indicator stops at 3/4 to the end and never calls refresh

This is how it looks like when you pull it all the way down:

[image]

Creating the refresh control:

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:
        #selector(TeamViewController.handleRefresh(_:)),
                             for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.red

    return refreshControl
}()
```

Adding to the view:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    myCollectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
} else {
    myCollectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and was caused by me setting the view controller to freeform in the storyboard as the simulated size. Changing it back to fixed resolved the issue.

Can also be fixed by using:

`override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        refreshControl?.didMoveToSuperview()
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }`

[UIRefreshControl needs to be pulled down too far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886365/uirefreshcontrol-needs-to-be-pulled-down-too-far)

Comment: omg... I've been debugging this issue for ages and _that_ was the problem! ‍♂️ thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: What the hell, how is this even possible?